# Filtering out desired data from a JSON file (Python)

Tags: python, json, dictionary

this is a sample of my json file:

```
{
"pops": [{
        "name": "pop_a",
        "subnets": {
            "Public": ["1.1.1.0/24,2.2.2.0/24"],
            "Private": ["192.168.0.0/24,192.168.1.0/24"],
        "more DATA":""  
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "pop_b",
        "subnets": {
            "Public": ["3.3.3.0/24,4.4.4.0/24"],
            "Private": ["192.168.2.0/24,192.168.3.0/24"],
        "more DATA":""
        }
    }
]
}
```

after i read it, i want to make a dic object and store some of the things that i need from this file.
i want my object to be like this ..

```
[{
    "name": "pop_a",
    "subnets": {"Public": ["1.1.1.0/24,2.2.2.0/24"],"Private": ["192.168.0.0/24,192.168.1.0/24"]}
},
{
    "name": "pop_b",
    "subnets": {"Public": ["3.3.3.0/24,4.4.4.0/24"],"Private": ["192.168.2.0/24,192.168.3.0/24"]}
}]
```

then i want to be able to access some of the public/private values

here is what i tried, and i know there is update(), setdefault()  that gave also same unwanted results

```
def my_funckion():
   nt_json = [{'name':"",'subnets':[]}]
   Pname = []
   Psubnet= []

   for pop in pop_json['pops']:  # it print only the last key/value
      nt_json[0]['name']= pop['name']
      nt_json[0]['subnet'] = pop['subnet']
   pprint (nt_json)

  for pop in pop_json['pops']: 
   """
     it print the names in a row then all of the ipss
   """
     Pname.append(pop['name'])
     Pgre.append(pop['subnet'])
     nt_json['pop_name'] = Pname
     nt_json['subnet']= Psubnet
   pprint (nt_json)
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to get output wise? what are you getting

Comment: you do not need to format the json file after importing it to a variable. Just use a for loop to find the key you want. And then use a nested for loop to find the keys in the nested dict.

Comment: The second data structure looks very much like the first one to me - so, what do you need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick solution using list comprehension. Note that this approach can be taken only with enough knowledge of the json structure.

```
>>> import json
>>>
>>> data = ... # your data
>>> new_data = [{ "name" : x["name"], "subnets" : {"Public" : x["subnets"]["Public"], "Private" : x["subnets"]["Private"]}} for x in data["pops"]]
>>>
>>> print(json.dumps(new_data, indent=2))
[
  {
    "name": "pop_a",
    "subnets": {
      "Private": [
        "192.168.0.0/24,192.168.1.0/24"
      ],
      "Public": [
        "1.1.1.0/24,2.2.2.0/24"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "pop_b",
    "subnets": {
      "Private": [
        "192.168.2.0/24,192.168.3.0/24"
      ],
      "Public": [
        "3.3.3.0/24,4.4.4.0/24"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: thank you  Coldspeed it worked for me . Can you please explain what indent=2 does ?

Comment: You can specify the number of spaces used to indent json. Root level = 0 spaces, level 1 = 2 spaces, level 2 = 4 spaces, ... and so on. If you change indent to 3, then it's 0, 3, 6, ... and so on.

Comment: thank you, and how can i print a specific pop from the new_data.. or pop names only... i'm unable to do so...

Comment: @IssaDaniel Currently your final structure is a list. If your pop names are unique, you could consider turning your final structure into a  list with pop names as key. The rest stays the same.